# Signing messages using ETH wallet - etherscan says that the Message Signature Hash is too short

Tags: ether, signature, message

I've got a problem with verifying ETH messages using etherscan.io (and the messages are signed using MyEtherWallet).

The signed message JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "address": "0xb49d0a635b0ec9508a775ba4f344af3db7293322",
    "msg": "0x656565",
    "sig": "224a0ae6ede23a8666ef8e5a9eb28a354ed24dacc676dd968031993c70ad80e903265341d13a1021a7a3724f276fe153d7b4ac9b25dcea883326efeda43f7e8f1b",
    "version": "3",
    "signer": "mnemonic"
}
```

When I paste the "sig" into "Message signature hash", I get an error message that it has "Invalid Length".

Strangely, it seems to be missing 2 characters every single time, but when I add the missing characters (and they are within the charset of the hash), in example `e1`, `11` , `b1` , `d4` - the verification passes.

Could it be that MyEtherWallet is doing something wrong? Or am I missing something?

I am fairly new to crypto, and I am trying to implement message verification mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You need to put **0x** in front of the sig.